# How to identify if Class reference is an interface?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air

As in Java I want to know if my reference is declared as Interface.

```
function foo(classRef:Class){

if(classRef.isInterface(){
  //something
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [AS3 Commons Reflect](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-reflect/index.html) to get this information. Your function would then look something like this:

```
function foo(classRef:Class)
{
    var type:Type = Type.forClass(classRef);

    if (type.isInterface)
    {
        //something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My own exploring. If class is interface, than in description XML in `<factory>` node it will never contain `<constructor>` and `<extendsClass>`. So, this is a function:

```
private function isInterface(type : *):Boolean {
        var description : XML = describeType(type);
        return (description.factory[0].descendants("constructor").length() == 0
                && description.factory[0].descendants("extendsClass").length() == 0);
}
```

Test:

```
trace(isInterface(IEventDispatcher));
trace(isInterface(Button));
trace(isInterface(int));
trace(isInterface(XML));
trace(isInterface(String));
```

Output:

```
[trace] true
[trace] false
[trace] false
[trace] false
[trace] false
```